# SQL syntax error with no known mistakes in query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting a syntax error for a very simple SQL query I'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO history (character, type, amount, extra)
VALUES('$character', '$type', '$amount', '$extra')
```

Here's the way the table is set up:

[SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlbNZ.png)

The full error it gives me is the following:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'character, type, amount, extra) VALUES('Ellie', 'Gift', '-200', 'to Rick')' at line 1

I've already checked and double checked the usual mistakes like the table name, spelling errors, column order etc, but I'm  clueless as to what it's still detecting, and hoping one of you can help me out...

Comment: amount is integer and use apostrophe. INSERT INTO history (`character`, `type`, `amount`, `extra`)
VALUES('$character', '$type', $amount, '$extra')

Comment: You `amount`column is `INTEGER` type that's why it refuses `-ve` value.

Change it to `unsigned` and then it will work. Also add back-ticks around `character`

Comment: stackoverflow does not show  back-ticks/apostrophe in comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`character` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql. Rename the column or use backticks for escaping it.

```
INSERT INTO history (`character`, type, amount, extra)
VALUES('$character', '$type', $amount, '$extra')
```

Comment: Actually, only `CHARACTER` is reserved, not `TYPE`, so only the former needs to be ticked. I did do an edit earlier to add "reserved", so you may want to readjust respectively ;-)

Comment: Awesome, I simply renamed the column to characterName instead of just character, and it works! Thank you all very much!